# Error while trying to update a database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am new to PHP and MySQL and I don't have anyone to help me so I am asking here. I was trying to update the database it shows some errors. Can anyone help me to correct the code below?

Database fields are `s.no`, `name`, `description`, `top_banner_image

Here is the code:

```
     <?
      php
       if(isset($_POST['submit']))
      {

       $product_name=$_POST['product_name'];
      $description=$_POST['description'];
      $photo_n=$_FILES['baner_image']['name'];
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES['top_banner_image']['tmp_name'],           

   $sql="INSERT INTO product_catergory (product_name, description, top_banner_image)
      VALUES
   ('$_POST[product_image]','$_POST[description]','$_POST[top_banner_image]')";

    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
    {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }
  echo "1 record added";

  mysqli_close($con);
 ?>
<?php include("foot.php"); ?>
```

Comment: **Warning** your code is extremely vulnerable to sql injection attack!

Comment: Forgot closing brace for `move_uploaded_file` function. Also if you taking post data into variable why you're using $_POST in your insert query ?

Comment: Well, what errors did you get? ;)

Comment: We cant help you fix an error if you dont tell us what the error is

Comment: First off, we need to know the error. Second, run your $_POST variables through a cleaning function, such as mysqli_real_escape_string(), otherwise $_POST vars containing apostrophes and other special characters can mess up the query and make your database exploitable (see Daniel's comment above).

Comment: Read and understand the error. Then troubleshoot to find where the error is coming from. You can probably narrow it down to one line. Then do some research on the problematic command and see what you're doing wrong.

Comment: in isset its shows error

Comment: You're also missing a closing bracket for the if(isset($_POST['submit'])) statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql="INSERT INTO `product_catergory` (`product_name`, `description`, `top_banner_image`)
      VALUES
   ('".$_POST[product_image]."','".$_POST[description]."','".$_POST[top_banner_image]."')";
```

By the way, you spelled "category" wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
$product_name=$_POST['product_name'];
$description=$_POST['description'];
$photo_n=$_FILES['baner_image']['name'];          

$sql="INSERT INTO product_category (product_name, description, top_banner_image) VALUES
('$_POST[product_image]','$_POST[description]','$_POST[top_banner_image]')";
```

the first thing that i see is wrong -> why are you making variables if you're not using them? `$product_name, $photo_n` are not used, `$description` should be in the insert statement, but if you have written `$_POST['description']` then that variable is not needed, also test on sql injection as was mentioned in comments by people